# how to make validation for two columns

Tags: laravel

I need a clean solution that's why I'm posting this.

So I have a formrequest validation which is the following:

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'restaurant_id' => 'required',
            'rating' => 'required',
            'comment' => 'required',
            'visited_at' => 'required|date'
        ];
    }
```

in controller, I also have user_id but request doesn't contain it. Now, I want to change the above rules so that user_id and restaurant_id both together will only be created only once. So for example . User_id 1 and restaurant_id 2 got saved as a row. If the same values come for these two columns, it should throw an error.

What would be the best and clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand the `exists` rule like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    $user = $this->user();

    return [
        'restaurant_id' => [
            'required',
             Rule::exists('YOUR_TABLE_NAME')->where(function ($query) use ($user) {                
                 $query->where('restaurant_id', request('restaurant_id'))
                       ->where('user_id', $user->id);
             })
        ],
        'rating' => 'required',
        'comment' => 'required',
        'visited_at' => 'required|date'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is so fine. It might happen that I might not have $this->user() instance in rules() function. is it possible to pass that from outside?

Comment: `$this->user()` is from the request, so unless you don't have anyone authenticated accessing this route, then that will return null. But then make a null check within the closure.